# Error Creating Multiple Containers with multiple Django projects

Tags: python, django, docker, containers, microservices

How to run multiple Django Projects as individual containers.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
web1:
   build: ./test1
   expose:
    - "8000"
   links:
    - postgres:postgres
   volumes:
    - /usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/static
   command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
web2:
   build: ./test2
   expose:
    - "3000"
   links:
    - postgres:postgres
   volumes:
    - /usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/static
   command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000
postgres:
   image: postgres:latest
   ports:
    - "5432:5432"
   volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

My Project Structure looks like this.

```
├── docker-compose.yml
└── test1
|    ├── Dockerfile
|    ├── test1
|    ├── manage.py
|    ├── requirements.txt
└── test2
|    ├── Dockerfile
|    ├── test2
|    ├── manage.py
|    ├── requirements.txt
```

This structure throws errors that file `manage.py` does not exist. Basically, the command is not looking for the file inside the folder.

I started from this Link - [Dockerizing Django](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/).

Comment: if you specify the full  path, like this: `command: python /usr/src/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`